# How to change the dbsqlite file ownership in gcp?

Tags: django, sqlite, google-cloud-platform

I have hosted my Django app to gcp. I am able to access the url aswell. But I am not able to login to the django admin panel. It gives me the following message.

[image]

As per what I read it seems to be a permission issue. How can I fix this problem?

NOTE: I dont want to use any cloud database. I want to stay with dbsqlite.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184630/open-sqlite-database-on-google-app-engine/41601943). You basically need to make sure that you copy the database file to the writeable /tmp directory of your GAE app. Notice that this is not a escalable approach as the database space will be using your RAM and you could get into OOM issues.

Comment: @Daniel Ocando Thanks. Looks like using dbsqlite with gcp is not advisable.